# XSLT grouping for wordml

Tags: xslt

Please can anybody help to find solution?

Requirement - using xslt 1.0

I have a xml structure like

```
<w:p xmlns:w="http://foo.com">
    <w:r>run1</w:r>
    <w:r>run2</w:r>
    <w:r>runn3</w:r>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>para1</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>para2</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:r>run4 - after para2</w:r>
    <w:r>run5- after para2</w:r>
   <w:p>
       <w:r>last para</w:r>
   </w:p>
</w:p>
```

Using xslt 1.0 I want output as follows:

```
<root>
 <w:p>
        <w:r>run1</w:r>
        <w:r>run2</w:r>
        <w:r>runn3</w:r>
        </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>para1</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>para2</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>run4 - after para2</w:r>
        <w:r>run5- after para2</w:r>
     </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>last para</w:r>
    </w:p>
</root>
```

basically i wanto group  inside  in sequence

XSLt which I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0" xmlns:w="http://foo.com" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

   <xsl:template match="/">   
       <root>
        <!--<xsl:for-each select="w:p/*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="name()='w:r'">
                    <w:p>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </w:p>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>-->
           <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r |w:p"/>
       </root>
   </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="w:r">
        <w:p>
             <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </w:p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="w:p/w:p">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root xmlns:w="http://foo.com" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <w:p>
        <w:r>run1</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>run2</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>runn3</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>para1</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>para2</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>run4 - after para2</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>run5- after para2</w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>last para</w:r>
    </w:p>
</root>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please edit the question to include your current XSLT.

Comment: Your expected output is missing the namespace declaration. Because you are still using the namespace prefix "w:" in the element names, you will need the namespace declaration to be present, or the XML will not be valid.

Comment: @Ian : This requirement is a small part of Wordml transformation. uptill now I have tried using for each loop , templates or diff ways by which i can get a expected output. the problem I am facing is I am able to push <W:r> inside <w:p> but what it does is it pushes all <w:r> inside <w:p> and outputs <w:P> from xml. which changes the sequence of text in my final wordml output

Comment: I have updated my question to include one of the solution I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ignore the existing `w:p` elements altogether here.  Ultimately what you want is a root element named `root` containing one `w:p` element for each run of adjacent `w:r` elements in the original source, regardless of whether or not those `w:r` elements were previously wrapped in a `w:p`.  You can approach this using a technique I call *sibling recursion* - start with a template that fires for the first `w:r` in each group and then have it recurse to its immediately following sibling until you hit one that isn't another `w:r`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0" xmlns:w="http://foo.com">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"
          select=".//w:r[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::w:r])]" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:r" mode="group">
    <w:p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." /><!-- applies non-"group" templates -->
    </w:p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:r">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::w:r]" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The magic is in the select expressions.

```
.//w:r[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::w:r])]
```

selects all `w:r` elements that do not immediately follow another `w:r` (i.e. the first one in each contiguous run).

```
following-sibling::*[1][self::w:r]
```

selects the immediately following sibling element of the current element, but *only* if it is a `w:r`.  The expression will select nothing if either there isn't a following sibling element at all, or there is one but it isn't a `w:r`.

Comment: :ohhh its brilliant...It generates expected output and solved my problem.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user2846094 glad it helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to _accept_ the answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left.  As well as rewarding the answerer this shows other readers at a glance that the problem is solved.

Comment: ohhh sorry. i was unaware of the process. this is my first question on stack overflow though i always refer it to find answers. i accepted the answer. thanks a lot again